# eclipse won't start - Unknown constant tag 110 error

Tags: java, eclipse, linux-mint

I am unable to start my Eclipse Indigo. when I start Eclipse, the blue welcome screen appears for about 1 second and then I get this error: `An error has occurred. See the log file:
/home/lukas/Develop/.metadata/.log.`

In the log there are these lines:

```
!SESSION 2014-05-15 13:29:48.212 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_30
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-05-15 13:29:50.044
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 110 in class file org/eclipse/ui/internal/intro/IIntroDescriptor
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.IntroRegistry.getIntros(IntroRegistry.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.intro.IntroRegistry.getIntroCount(IntroRegistry.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1501)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$36(Workbench.java:1486)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$66.run(Workbench.java:2597)
```

I'm using Linux Mint 13 Maya LTS 64. My Eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1536m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms400m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

I didn't change any settings recently, I simply restarted Eclipse.

Comment: Did this Eclipse installation already succeed to start?

Comment: yes i'm working with it since 2 months ago